# Datatables - Can't remove and add data smoothly

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to remove all data and add new ones using datatables on button press, but I can't run this procress smoothly.
I can achieve this only when I load for the first time, but then the information pop out and pop in, I thougth to hide the tables, remove the information, add the new ones and show the tables again, but when I run this process it hides, do some stuff, show again, pop out old information and adds new one.
 This is my code:

```
var utab,otab,atab;
    $.ajax({type: 'POST',url: '../php/function.php',data: {<?php echo $_SESSION['token']['act']; ?>:'retrive_tickets',stat:1},dataType : 'json',
        success : function (a) {
            $('.loading').remove();
            if(a.response=='ret'){

                    utab=$("#usertable").dataTable({
                            sDom:"<<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                            sWrapper:"dataTables_wrapper form-inline",
                            bDestroy:true,
                            bProcessing:true,
                            aaSorting:[[2,"desc"]],
                            oLanguage:{sEmptyTable:"No Tickets"},
                            aoColumns:[{sTitle:"Title",mDataProp:"title",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Title: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Created Date",mDataProp:"date",sWidth:"140px",sClass:"visible-desktop",bVisible:!1,fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Created Date: </strong></span><span> " + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Last Reply",mDataProp:"reply",sWidth:"140px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Last Reply: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Department",mDataProp:"dname",sClass:"hidden-phone",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Department: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Operator",mDataProp:"opname", sClass:"visible-desktop",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Operator: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Priority",mDataProp:"priority",sWidth:"75px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Priority: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Toggle",mDataProp:"action",bSortable:!1,bSearchable:!1,sWidth:"60px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Toggle: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}}]}),

                    otab=$("#operatortable").dataTable({
                            sDom:"<<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                            sWrapper:"dataTables_wrapper form-inline",
                            bDestroy:true,
                            bProcessing:true,
                            aaSorting:[[2,"desc"]],
                            oLanguage:{sEmptyTable:"No Tickets"},
                            aoColumns:[{sTitle:"Title",mDataProp:"title",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Title: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Created Date",mDataProp:"date",sWidth:"140px",sClass:"visible-desktop",bVisible:!1,fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Created Date: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Last Reply",mDataProp:"reply",sWidth:"140px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Last Reply: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Department",mDataProp:"dname",sClass:"hidden-phone",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Department: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Operator",mDataProp:"opname", sClass:"visible-desktop",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Operator: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Priority",mDataProp:"priority",sWidth:"80px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Priority: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Status",mDataProp:"status",sWidth:"80px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Status: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Toggle",mDataProp:"action",bSortable:!1,bSearchable:!1,sWidth:"60px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Toggle: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}}]}),

                    atab=$("#admintable").dataTable({
                            sDom:"<<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                            sWrapper:"dataTables_wrapper form-inline",
                            bDestroy:true,
                            bProcessing:true,
                            aaSorting:[[2,"desc"]],
                            oLanguage:{sEmptyTable:"No Tickets"},
                            aoColumns:[{sTitle:"Title",mDataProp:"title",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Title: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Created Date",mDataProp:"date",sWidth:"140px",sClass:"visible-desktop",bVisible:!1,fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Created Date: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Last Reply",mDataProp:"reply",sWidth:"140px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Last Reply: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Department",mDataProp:"dname",sClass:"hidden-phone",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Department: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Operator",mDataProp:"opname", sClass:"visible-desktop",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Operator: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Priority",mDataProp:"priority",sWidth:"80px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Priority: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Status",mDataProp:"status",sWidth:"80px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Status: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}},{sTitle:"Toggle",mDataProp:"action",bSortable:!1,bSearchable:!1,sWidth:"60px",fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {$(nTd).html("<span><strong class='visible-phone'>Toggle: </strong></span><span>" + $(nTd).html() + '</span>');}}]});

                    var l=a.tickets.user.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.user[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                    utab.fnAddData(a.tickets.user);

                    var l=a.tickets.op.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.op[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.op[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.op[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                    otab.fnAddData(a.tickets.op);

                    var l=a.tickets.admin.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.admin[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.admin[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.admin[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                    atab.fnAddData(a.tickets.admin);


            }
            else
                noty({text:a[0],type:"error",timeout:9E3});
        }
    }).fail(function(b,a){noty({text:a,type:"error",timeout:9E3})});

    $(document).on('click','#tkopen', function(){
        $('#tkstatnav > li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.dataTables_wrapper').each(function(){
            $(this).hide(400);
            $(this).before("<img id='loading' class='loading' src='../css/images/loader.gif' alt='Loading' title='Loading'/>");
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({type: 'POST',url: '../php/function.php',data: {<?php echo $_SESSION['token']['act']; ?>:'retrive_tickets',stat:1},dataType : 'json',
                success : function (a) {
                    if(a.response=='ret'){

                            var l=a.tickets.user.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.user[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                                $.when(utab.fnClearTable()).then(utab.fnAddData(a.tickets.user));
                            var l=a.tickets.op.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.op[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.op[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.op[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                                $.when(otab.fnClearTable()).then(otab.fnAddData(a.tickets.op));
                            var l=a.tickets.admin.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.admin[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.admin[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.admin[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                                $.when(atab.fnClearTable()).then(atab.fnAddData(a.tickets.admin));
                    }
                    else
                        noty({text: 'Ticket cannot be deleted. Error: '+data[0],type:'error',timeout:9000});
                }
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){noty({text: textStatus,type:'error',timeout:9000});});

            $.when($('.loading').remove()).then($('.dataTables_wrapper').each(function(){$(this).show(400);}));
        },800);
    });

    $(document).on('click','#tkclosed', function(){
        $('#tkstatnav > li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.dataTables_wrapper').each(function(){
            $(this).hide(400);
            $(this).before("<img id='loading' class='loading' src='../css/images/loader.gif' alt='Loading' title='Loading'/>");
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.when(
                $.ajax({type: 'POST',url: '../php/function.php',data: {<?php echo $_SESSION['token']['act']; ?>:'retrive_tickets',stat:0},dataType : 'json',
                    success : function (a) {
                        if(a.response=='ret'){

                                var l=a.tickets.user.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.user[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                                    $.when(utab.fnClearTable()).then(utab.fnAddData(a.tickets.user));
                                var l=a.tickets.op.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.op[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.op[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.op[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                                    $.when(otab.fnClearTable()).then(otab.fnAddData(a.tickets.op));
                                var l=a.tickets.admin.length;if(l>0){for(i=0;i<l;i++)$.extend(a.tickets.admin[i],{title:'<button class="btn btn-link viewtk" value="'+a.tickets.user[i].id+'">'+a.tickets.user[i].title+"</button>",action:'<div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-warning editusr" value="'+a.tickets.admin[i].id+'"><i class="icon-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger remusr" value="'+a.tickets.admin[i].id+'"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button></div>'});} 
                                    $.when(atab.fnClearTable()).then(atab.fnAddData(a.tickets.admin));

                        }
                        else
                            noty({text: 'Ticket cannot be deleted. Error: '+data[0],type:'error',timeout:9000});
                    }
                }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){noty({text: textStatus,type:'error',timeout:9000});}),

                $('.loading').remove()
            ).then($('.dataTables_wrapper').each(function(){$(this).show(400);}));
        },800);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce / decrypt your code (jsFiddle?) but it seems to me that you over complicate it to much. Here is what I do, example - clear the datatabled' `<table>` and insert 100 new rows, no hide or flickering - guess your `setTimeout`'s is most to blame :

```
$("#clear").click(function() {
   dataTable.fnClearTable();
   for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
      dataTable.fnAddData([
         'RenderingEngine #'+i,
         'Browser #'+i,
         'Platforms #'+i,
         'EngineVersion #'+i,
         'CSS Grade #'+i
       ]);
  }
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/DQj5r/ -

Comment: I used that function because I need to delay the ajax call, is there a way to achive this?